# Как организовать проверку двух японских свечей

Tags: tradingview, pinescript

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться в PineScript.
Суть задачи такова:
Имеются фракталы на графике как с помощью PineScript сделать проверку на то что если две свечи "подряд" идущие имеют максимум и минимум как на фотографии то поставить на 3ую свечу табличку "HQS"(Для понимание приложил скриншот)
Как рисуются фракталы понятно а вот как сделать данную проверку не совсем понятно.Заранее спасибо
[image: Паттерн двух подряд идущих свечей минимум и максимум]

Comment: "как на фотографии" это как именно? В четких понятных измеряемых критериях.

Comment: Как на фотографии две японские свечи имеют максимум и минимум,неважно красные или зеленые то следующая свеча обозначается "HQD"(но есть случай когда сначала идет минимум потом максимум такие случаи игнорировать)

Comment: Помечай все. Ведь у каждой свечи есть максимум и минимум.